# AGIC with App gateway together with azure load balancer

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

i want to understand the concept and the traffic flow in case of using AGIC. I'm using azure advanced networking in AKS. What i see that azure automatically creates an Azure load balancer once the cluster is created. So now i have an App gateway working together with AGIC . So what's the role of the Azure load balancer in this case?. And how then the traffic will flow ingress and igress of the cluster?. Should also the load balancer have a public IP ? Any explanation or resources would be very helpful.